# Bash scripting - using if in a for loop

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I am total noob in bash scripting and do not know what the problem is within my code;
I am writing an sh extension file that will be used as a buffer into the Linux sys.
This is just a practice but I do not know what the problem within the code really is, can someone tell me?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text?more_on=xron.net). People here regard that as evil.

Comment: Post relevant parts of the code that you've tried, show the errors you got, and the effort you made. Show example output, and example Input of your input files..

Comment: Sorry, I was using a virtual machine and I had limited time on it. 
I will now try to write the code I wrote.

Comment: Also, please specify what problem you are having. (What does it do what? What are you trying to accomplish, etc)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the answer I came up with in the end

```
#!/bin/bash
>oldFiles.txt
files=$(grep ' jane ' ../data/list.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 3)
for x in $files;
do 
    if test -e ../data/$x; then echo $x >> oldFiles.txt; else echo $x; fi;
done
```

Comment: It's best if answers explains why the changes were made. Code dumps without explanations aren't useful to anyone.

Comment: Tip: `;` is used to put two commands on the same line. There's no point in ending a line with `;`.

Comment: @Ron, This is purportedly the solution, so posting it as an answer is appropriate.